# display a photo on jsp file using a url

Tags: java, jsp, url, photo, blobstore

I'm trying to display a photo on my jsp file. a photo that is inside my images photos works fine but when i'm trying to retrieve a photo using a url from the internet it doesnt work.
my url is a link of a database domain.I'm saving my photos using blobstore in that domain and retrieve them later.
I know the link works fine because when I use it in my explorer I receive the photo I uploded so what could be wrong? or is there a better way to display photos on a jsp file using blobStore ?
I'v search the web for something similar but all the solutions are for photos save in the program or not displaying on jsp.

my code in the jsp file is :

```
          <%String blob=request.getParameter("blob");
           BlobKey blobKey = new BlobKey(blob);
           ImagesService services = ImagesServiceFactory.getImagesService();
           ServingUrlOptions serve = ServingUrlOptions.Builder.withBlobKey(blobKey);    
           String url = services.getServingUrl(serve);
           %>
           <center><img src="url" alt='photo'/></center>
```

I've tried printing the url I received to make sure it is the right path and it works fine when I put it in my explorer so what could be the problem ? thanks for your help

Comment: As a side note: [The use of scriptlets in JSP is highly discouraged](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3180202/814702)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Syntax error.You cannot access variable like that. Have you tried the following?

```
<img src="<%= url %>" />
```

Comment: @user1596497 No issues.Happens to everyone,Please mark it as answer if you found useful.Good luck with the project.